# Sort a Net. ArrayList filled with class objects basing on the objects' default value in VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList as a manageable container of some objects.

```
    Dim DevIdArray As Object
    Set DevIdArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

The main idea behind that was using .Sort method of ArrayList.

The items' class IdContainer contains .text, and .time properties (with intention to use more in the future),
where .text is a *default* property, i.e. for every "id" object id.text="string" is equal to id="string".
So it is just a way of holding metadata for every meaningful text record.

In VBA I cannot directly .Add(id) such "id" object to the ArrayList, because it will add just the default "id.text" property as a pure String there. Therefore I add a *dummy* object of my class IdContainer, and then copy the pointer of my data there:

```
Private id as idContainer 
Set id = New iDcontainer '_allocate_ the actual data
id = textbuffer
id.time = time  'record my "metadata"

...<later archiving the built object>...
DevIdArray.Add (New iDcontainer) 'create a dummy object, so the item holds its type.
Set DevIdArray.Item(DevIdArray.Count - 1) = id 'swap its pointer to the real data.
Set id = Nothing 'clear the original pointer. The data now belongs solely to the ArrayList.Item
'(I do not know how to cast the IdContainer type to the ArrayList.Item() without allocating a dummy in VBA)
```

No matter how strange the above, I get my ListArray filled with my class objects.

But DevIdArray.Sort does not work.

Apparently, the .Sort method is not aware of the "default" value of my objects.

Is there a simple way to sort such ListArray basing on default values, without coding the sorting algorithm, which should be aware of default values and all the metadata from the scratch?

Comment: What do you expect from `DevIdArray.Sort`, `DevIdArray` containing objects? Based of what do you expect it to sort the contained objects? A `ListArray` is able to sort strings. Only ascending. In order to sort descending you should use `ArList.Reverse` after sorting... I am not able to understand how a list of objects can be sorted, no offence. Nothing can sort objects based on their "default" values, if you do not write such a function able to use the respective "default" value. From this point of view, you could use a simple array, with a similar behavior (when using a sorting Function/Sub.

Comment: .Add(id) is incorrect in VBA.  You have actually written .add (Id).  Note the space between the .add and the opening bracket.  The brackets mean that (Id) is an expression which in your case evaluates to the default member value which is why you get the string value.  Try just .Add Id,

Comment: ArrayList is also only available on devices with .NET Framework 3.5 installed (which it is not, by default, on Windows 10+). As per @FaneDuru, you could use a 'normal' array and implement your own sort ... such as (full disclosure: this is my site) [Sorting Objects in VBA](https://www.thevbahelp.com/post/sorting-objects-in-vba)

Comment: FaneDuru. I don't care which sorting, as long at it is fast and produces repeatable results on mixed symbols.  
JohnM, as I said, the idea was using protected managed array with tools like sorting, or tag search implemented. Standard array does not doo that. For some reason I have no problem with calling the System.Collections.ArrayList nowhere. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0
.NET Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.8.1

Comment: So, hoping that it sorts by calling the value,I made this metadata container with default value. But it probably(I guess) reads the raw data by a fixed type pointer from the memory, and stops when sees an object.

Comment: well. implemented it with an external function, as far as I know it. Very slow and inheritance is not possible in VBA which makes everything cluttered. It appeared that text search also does not work on object members; even when they return string by default.